# dbExpress how to show result from query?

Tags: mysql, delphi

```
var
  Connection: TSQLConnection;
  SqlSet:TSQLDataSet;
begin
  Connection := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
  SqlSet := TSQLDataSet.Create(nil);
  SqlSet.SQLConnection:=Connection;
  Connection.DriverName := 'MySQL';
  Connection.GetDriverFunc := 'getSQLDriverMYSQL';
  Connection.LibraryName := 'dbxmys.dll';
  Connection.VendorLib := 'libmysql.dll';
  Connection.LoginPrompt:=False;


  Connection.Params.Values['Database']:=('shadowxx1');
  Connection.Params.Values['User_Name']:=('shadowxx1');
  Connection.Params.Values['Password']:=('shadowxx1');
  Connection.Params.Values['HostName']:=('shadowxx1');
  Connection.Open;
  Connection.Connected:=True;

  SqlSet.CommandType:=ctQuery;
  SqlSet.CommandText:= 'SELECT VERSION()';
  SqlSet.ExecSQL;


  Connection.Close;
  Connection.Free;
  SqlSet.Free;
end;
```

Code working , but , how to show result of query or extract it to the grid??? 
I simply dont find this information, in ADO it was smth like this

```
DataSrc := TDataSource.Create(Self);
DataSrc.DataSet := ADOQuery;
DataSrc.Enabled := true;
DBGrid1.DataSource := DataSrc;
```

If someone can - give some examples

And like this dont work 
[image]

Comment: Yes, it does work. There is information on using data aware controls in the Delphi [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Using_Data_Controls). For the ADO controls and TDBGrid, using a TDataSource, this hasn't changed at all since the ADO components were introduced in Delphi 5. (Of course, you have to make sure you've written a valid SELECT statement in the first place that will return rows.)

Comment: In ADO , i shouldn't add any. I only send query and recieve table. NOthing else.And how to do it? Can u give simple examle? I Added Screenshot in my original post

Comment: @TLama: `VERSION()` is a [built-in function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_version) in MySQL.

Comment: @Ken, yup, I know. I meant with my previous comment if OP has a column in the grid. But then he posted a screenshot which is IMHO related to the [`command type`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TPSCommandType) used. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with those types. Cool, I accidentally found [`Delphi 2007 online help`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TSQLCommandType.html) :-)

Comment: I dont understand this stupid components. Realy , i dont neet visual table. Can i acces to the information , that returned from query??? Why its so hard to take a result from function SqlSet.ExecSQL;

Comment: @TLama: Yeah, I know. A single row from a non-scrollable dataset doesn't lend itself well to being added to a `TDBGrid`.

Comment: Can i acces to the information , that returned from query??? Why its so hard to take a result from function SqlSet.ExecSQL; ??

Comment: It's not about hard or not. It's because of what reference says about [`ExecSQL`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLDataSet.ExecSQL): *"Executes a query or stored procedure* ***that does not return a set of records***"

Comment: It's not hard at all, if you read the documentation. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong method. In any of the `TDataSet` descendants that have it, `ExecSQL` is for executing queries that return no result set, such as INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE TABLE. See, for instance, [`TSQLQuery.ExecSQL`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLQuery.ExecSQL) (**emphasis** mine)

> Executes a query that **does not return a set of records.**
>
> Call ExecSQL to execute an SQL command that does not return a set of records. **This command is a query** other than a SELECT query, **such as an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE TABLE query.**

Use `TSQLQuery.Open` to return rows from a SELECT. Something like this should work (untested - I don't use MySQL or DBExpress):

```
var
  Qry: TSQLQuery;
  VersionString: String;


  // Set up your connection as above, and open it

  Qry := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  Qry.SQLConnection := Connection;

  Qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT VERSION() as DBVersion';
  Qry.Open;

  if not Qry.IsEmpty then
    VersionString := Qry.FieldByName('DBVersion').AsString
  else
    VersionString := 'No results found';
  Qry.Close;
```

For more information (including step-by-step tutorials), see [Using DBExpress Components](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Using_dbExpress_Components_Index) at the Delphi docwiki. (The one I've linked is for the current Delphi version, but the basic steps for DBExpress are the same since it was introduced.)

If you want a basic video tutorial for using DBExpress in Delphi, you can try [DBExpress Data Access Components in Delphi - Delphi 101](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNWerq-Qebo). I haven't watched it, but it was posted by Embarcadero, the makers of Delphi.

Comment: Oh, thank you... Its realy hard to all day fight with delphi -_-.

Comment: Dealing with dbXpress you always have to use a TClientDataSet because **all** dbXpress Datasets are **unidirectional**. http://delphi.about.com/od/database/a/dbexpressguide.htm and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Building_a_VCL_Forms_dbExpress_Database_Application

Comment: @SirRufo: Not *always*. Only when you want to be able to move backward. If all you're doing is moving forward, you don't need a CDS. Of course, you wouldn't need a DBGrid, either. :-)

Comment: The question is about "how to show result" and the unidirectional error message. But you answered the **real** question from OP ;o)

Comment: Can you show more example , or links , where normaly shown how to get result of query ? If simply its rows and columns... How to work with it?

Comment: @SirRufo: The question asked is in the title: "How to show result from query?". The poster being way off track with a DBGrid, SQLDataSet, and ExecSQL was the problem. A CDS wouldn't have changed that at all. :-)

Comment: @ShadowFrost: What version of Delphi are you using? Most of them have demo applications that show the basics, as does the documentation. The easiest way to do it is to drop the appropriate data controls on a TDataModule, connect them all at design time in the IDE, use that datamodule in the unit where your DB controls are going to show, and then just set the SQL and open the query at run time, and everything takes care of itself.

Comment: The link you asked for: [Using DBExpress Components](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Using_dbExpress_Components_Index). Start at the top, and it will take you right through setting them up, using them, and displaying results.

Comment: Using XE2 ver. Demo wasnt found in rad studio folder. Realy all day with this DB , its makin" me crazy . In PHP , i made it in 20 minutes with knowledge in syntax only. But delphi... somthing wrong. I understand , why people are going to C languages

Comment: You clearly haven't tried using datasets in C#. :-) Bashing the language because you can't be bothered to read the documentation is simply wrong.

Comment: Maybe, but , i read all this time more , and more info , but nothing understad.
Can you give example how to parse smth like `SELECT * FROM ...`

Comment: I've referred you to step by step instructions twice, that have examples you can follow directly. How is my writing them again going to change things? I've also previously said I don't use DBExpress or MySQL; I posted my answer based on what I figured out with a quick look at the documentation.

Comment: Here - I've googled "dbexpress tutorial mysql" for you, and found [this](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/a/dbexpressguide.htm) as the very first result. If you prefer a video tutorial, you can [use this one instead](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNWerq-Qebo). There are others listed as well if you repeat that search. Good luck.

Comment: I've answered the question asked here, pointed you to a written tutorial, a video tutorial, and the documentation's step-by-step instructions. I don't know what more I can do for you here. I've said (and will repeat again for the **third** time), **I don't use MySQL or DBExpress**. I have nothing to use to test any code for you, and I certainly wouldn't write a tutorial to post here without being able to test it along the way, and I've guided you to three sources for tutorials already that you won't follow. I'd suspect you're looking for copy/paste code, and I don't have that to offer.

Comment: In that "Step to step " is NOTHING about how to get one row from SELECT * FROM . Yes? Yes. This code not working 

 `Qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM ayah';

    Qry.Open;

    while not Qry.Eof do
    begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('LINEOLOLOO');

        Qry.Next;
    end;`

Comment: I've shown you already that to access a field by it's name, you use `FieldByName`. If you **won't even read the code I've already given you**, won't follow tutorials I Google for you because you don't do it yourself, and can't follow step by step instructions in the documentation, I can't possibly help you any further. Please stop adding more comments here.