# Unknown MYSQL server host 'ServerName'(11001)

Tags: mysql, delphi, dbexpress

I want to try connection with `MySQL`database with my `Delphi` Application.
I am using `dbXpress` component `TSQLConnection`.

When I tried using the Graphic component and test it if it can connect Database.
It got connected with using Object inspector option.

But when I tried using the code I am getting error as **Unknown MYSQL server host 'ServerName'(11001)**.

I am not able to get the right solution from google uncle.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Below is My Code.

```
      Conn := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
  try
    conn.DriverName:= 'MySQL';
    conn.Params.Add('HostName=127.0.0.1');
    conn.Params.Add('Database=test1');
    conn.Params.Add('UserName=root');
    conn.Params.Add('Password=test');
    conn.LoginPrompt := false;
    try
    conn.Connected := true;
    ShowMessage('Database connected');
    Except
      on E:exception do
       ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  finally
   if Conn.Connected then
     Conn.Connected :=  false;
   FreeAndNil(Conn);
  end;
```

Please let me know if any more information needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks like you are not setting all properties. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21444177/800214) for a complete example how to setup dbexpress with mysql from code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `conn.Params` list is already propagated with pre-existing values. Therefore you should not `.add()` your configuration to it, but rather change the current `Params`.

So, instead of using

```
conn.Params.Add('HostName=127.0.0.1'); // wrong - should update, not add
conn.Params.Add('Database=test1'); // wrong - should update, not add
conn.Params.Add('UserName=root'); // wrong - should update, not add
conn.Params.Add('Password=test'); // wrong - should update, not add
```

Use

```
conn.Params.Values['HostName'] := '127.0.0.1';
conn.Params.Values['Database'] := 'test1';
conn.Params.Values['UserName'] := 'root';
conn.Params.Values['Password'] := 'test';
```